# Not able to get the date values from the datepicker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pickup dates. I have JavaScript code and I don't know where I am doing wrong. There is a start date and a end date in the code below.

I need to pick up date from the form which is based on JavaScript. The two functions and details are given below. Please have a look at the code and let me know where could the issue be.

```
function valuation_date_from(maxDate) {
        var d = new Date();
        var startDate = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
        var datepicker1 = {
            singleDatePicker: true,
            calender_style: "picker_3",
            timePicker: true,
            startDate: startDate,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            minDate: startDate,
            timePickerIncrement: 5,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a',
            onSelect:function(){
                alert();
            }
        };
        if (maxDate != '') {
            datepicker1.maxDate =PrevDay(maxDate);
        }
        $('#valuation_date_from').daterangepicker(datepicker1, function(start, end, label) {
           // console.log(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'));

            valuation_date_to(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'),$('#pricing_date_from').val());
            if($('#valuation_date_to').val()==""){
                pricing_date_from('',start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'));
            }
            if($('#pricing_date_from').val()==""){
                pricing_date_to(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'));
            }
        });
    }
```

and date to:

```
function valuation_date_to(minDate,maxDate) {
        var d = new Date();
        var startDate = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
        var datepicker2 = {
            singleDatePicker: true,
            minDate: startDate,
            startDate: nextDay(minDate),
            calender_style: "picker_3",
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            timePickerIncrement: 5,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'
        };
        if (minDate != '') {
            datepicker2.minDate = nextDay(minDate);
        }
        if (maxDate != '') {
            datepicker2.maxDate = PrevDay(maxDate);
        }
        $('#valuation_date_to').daterangepicker(datepicker2, function(start, end, label) {
            valuation_date_from(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'));
            pricing_date_from($('#pricing_date_to').val(),start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'));
            if($('#pricing_date_from').val()==""){
                pricing_date_to(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'));
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: where is the demo page? you dumped tons of code here.. what is `daterangepicker` ??

Comment: @vsync I think he is using http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: please make a jsfiddle e.g for better understanding code so that we can help you quickly.